# How to increase window height longer than the screen height in applescript?

Tags: applescript

I have such an AppleScript:

```
tell application "Firefox"
    activate
    set the bounds of the first window to {0, 0, 6000, 6000}
end tell
```

But this code doesn't let me to re-size the height of the window higher than the screen bounds.

How can I make this happen?

p.s. The window width is set to 6000px successfully, but no luck with window height.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the OS doesn't let you resize the height of ANY window higher than screen bounds, which is probably why you're hitting this limitation. Which means, there's no acceptable solution for your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I searched for several days, tried several methods and I think there's no way to make this available.

Comment: Yeah, I did some simple experimentation myself, and I found that it is possible to adjust the width of a window beyond screen bounds, but not height.