# Set window height to be larger than screen height

Tags: c#, windows, console-application

Does anyone know if its actually possible to set the height of a window such that it is greater than the screen size using C#?

I tried something like this on several windows:

```
SetWindowPos(handle, new IntPtr(0), 0, 0, 1024, 4000, 
             SetWindowPosFlags.SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
```

However, they never go past the screen size - is there a way around this?

Comment: [This is something similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344615/how-to-increase-window-height-longer-than-the-screen-height-in-applescript). Although being for Apple, I do think the same applies for Windows.

Comment: I think the max height is enforced by the `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` handler, so if you could override the window procedure, then you could call the default window proc and then alter the return value before returning. That said, you tagged this as "console-application", and I don't think you'll be able to override the window proc for a console window.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the size of a Form in Visual Studio designer limited to screen resolution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6651115/is-the-size-of-a-form-in-visual-studio-designer-limited-to-screen-resolution)

Comment: No, you can't do this. There's no reason for a window to be larger than the screen.

Comment: @CodyGray - this is possible. I've seen many applications do this. Furthermore, I think I'm the only person that can say if there is a need for this or not. :)

Comment: This can be controlled by an application by handling the WM_GETMINMAXINFO message.  But you're messing with apps that are not yours, you'd need a window hook to trap that message.  But WH_CALLWNDPROCRET is a global hook, you can't write those in C#.

Comment: @HansPassant I too have seen JetVideo doing this, my max screen resolution is 1430x900 when I played a 1920x1060 video at 100% it stretched outside the screen and i could only see the clipped region of the window, so they could be using some hacks to do that. Could be looked into.

Comment: @Shekhar: Are you sure that the *window* was actually larger than the screen, rather than the video was just cut off?

Comment: @CodyGray They have their custom designed window chrome and it was greater than max screen resolution.. I am not much experienced in using spy++ but you may try checking it. Take any small video convert it to a scaled video of greater resolution (use handbrake) and play it in JetVideo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No its not allowed though you are using `SetWindowPos` the MSDN docs on  [Form.Size](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25w4thew.aspx) property says:

> The maximum value of this property is limited **by the resolution** of the screen on which the form runs. The value cannot be greater than 12 pixels over each screen dimension (horizontal + 12 and vertical + 12).

Comment: I've also used the `MoveWindow` and that too doesn't work. Are there any other alternatives?

Comment: @Abs One alternative seems to be mentioned in [this answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6651523/399722) which suggests to use a Panel in the form.